# ASP.NET MVC 5 Application - XSS Code Security Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

Would you please help fix this security issue

```
function() {  
                var data = $('#tbCommitteeMembers').DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
                var role = $(this).val();
                if (role==0) {
                    vroAlert.displayAlert('warning', 'Error2', 'Error');
                    return;
                } else {

               
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: `/CommitteeMembers/SetCommitteeMemberRole?Id=${data.Id}&RoleId=${role}`,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data) {

                            vroAlert.displayAlert('success', '@GlobalLP.SavedSuccessfully',
                                '@GlobalLP.SavedSuccessfully');
                            $('#tbCommitteeMembers').DataTable().ajax.reload();


                        },
                        error: function(error) {

                            console.error("Error", error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

}

Would you please help if this line contains any code security issue and how to fix?

```
url: `/CommitteeMembers/SetCommitteeMemberRole?Id=${data.Id}&RoleId=${role}`,
```

BTW, Although RoleId and Data.Id are numeric values I'm getting security error on the above line of code!

Comment: As I understood, this code just got data from webserer and viewed some data in table. XSS error possible if your server does not cast `Id` and `RoleId` to int

Comment: Thanks ... It was a false bug from security